# Transforming a Flow<Byte> to a Flow<String> in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

Consider I have a *cold* source of UTF-8 bytes (e. g.: reading a file on disk, or the body of an HTTP response), in a form of a `Flow<Byte>`. How do I convert the above source to a *flow* of strings?

In other words, I want the following behaviour:

```kotlin
        /*
         * A multi-line string, not terminated with a newline character.
         */
        val string = """
            first line
            第二行
            третья строка
        """.trimIndent()

        assertNotEquals('\n', string.last())
        assertEquals(2, string.asSequence().count { it == '\n' })

        val source: Flow<Byte> = string.toByteArray().asSequence().asFlow()

        val transformed: Flow<String> = TODO()

        val target = runBlocking {
            transformed.toList(mutableListOf()).toTypedArray()
        }

        assertArrayEquals(
            arrayOf("first line", "第二行", "третья строка"),
            target
        )
```

As an extra restriction, this is a Kotlin/JS project, so `java.io` APIs can't be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I came up with the following solution:

```kotlin
fun Flow<Byte>.decodeToString(): Flow<String> =
    flow {
        val buffer: MutableList<Byte> = arrayListOf()

        collect { value ->
            when (value) {
                /*
                 * Ignore.
                 */
                '\r'.code.toByte() -> Unit

                '\n'.code.toByte() -> {
                    emit(buffer)
                    buffer.clear()
                }

                else -> buffer.add(value)
            }
        }

        if (buffer.isNotEmpty()) {
            emit(buffer)
        }
    }
        .map(Collection<Byte>::toByteArray)
        .map(ByteArray::decodeToString)
```

The `ArrayList<Byte>` above can be replaced with either `okio.Buffer` from [*okio*](https://square.github.io/okio/3.x/okio/okio/okio/index.html) or `kotlinx.io.core.BytePacketBuilder` from [*kotlinx-io*](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-io/), e.g.:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import okio.Buffer

fun Flow<Byte>.decodeToString(): Flow<String> =
    flow {
        val buffer = Buffer()

        collect { value ->
            when (value) {
                /*
                 * Ignore.
                 */
                '\r'.code.toByte() -> Unit

                '\n'.code.toByte() -> {
                    emit(buffer.readUtf8())
                    buffer.clear()
                }

                else -> buffer.writeByte(value.toInt())
            }
        }

        if (buffer.size > 0) {
            emit(buffer.readUtf8())
        }
    }
```